# How can i access Google APIs from NodeJS REST API?

Tags: node.js, rest, google-chrome-extension, google-api

I want to create a REST Api using NodeJS and make a request to some google apis(like gmail, contact and people api). I have created a project in google developer console and then enabled all necessary google apis in my project. Now when creating credentials(selected OAuth client ID), i am confused to choose the application type among 'Web application' and 'Others'. If i choose Web Application then what will be the value for **Authorized JavaScript origins** and **Authorized redirect URIs**

**Note: I will be using this REST API for a chrome extension and an IOS app later.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/+/web/samples/javascript

states
"Note: Use a single project to hold all platform instances of your app (Android, iOS, web, etc.), each with a different Client ID."
Which means you would be fine selecting Web Application for your needs.

Comment: do u mean to say that I should generate separate Client ID for Chrome App and IOS App? Since my API will be same for both apps, I need to switch between Client IDs when making a request to google apis. Is this the way to do it?